# Cross-thread operation not valid during multiple event handling

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface

I'm having UI issues in a Windows Forms application. I know there are countless posts on the Internet regarding this issue but I still could not find an appropriate solution.

I have this method:

```
private void AddContactTile(ContactTile c)
{
    if (mainPanel.InvokeRequired)
    {
        AddContactTileDelegate ctdelegate = new AddContactTileDelegate(AddContactTile);
        mainPanel.BeginInvoke(ctdelegate, c);
    }
    else
    {
        mainPanel.Controls.Add(c);
    }
}
```

and this method:

```
private void ChangeTileStatus(string userid)
{
    ContactTile tile = contactTiles.Find(x => x.Key == userid).Value;
    if (tile.statusLabel.InvokeRequired)
    {
        ChangeTileStatusDelegate ctsdelegate = new ChangeTileStatusDelegate(ChangeTileStatus);
        tile.statusLabel.BeginInvoke(ctsdelegate, userid);
    }
    else
    {
        if (contacts.ContainsKey(userid))
        {
            tile.statusLabel.Visible = contacts[userid].IsAvailable;
            tile.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

both of which are called in event handlers. Now since the events may be raised concurrently I am receiving an Invalid cross-thread operation message on the `statusLabel` control in the `AddContactTile` method.

Does anyone know a way to synchronise these accesses properly? Thanks.

Code for the `AddContact` method:

```
public void AddContact(FacebookUser user)
{
    contacts[user.id].DisplayPictureAvailable += new EventHandler<UserEventArgs>(Contacts_DisplayPictureAvailable);
    contacts[user.id].StatusChanged += new EventHandler<UserEventArgs>(Contacts_StatusChanged);
    ContactTile c = new ContactTile(user.name, user.id) { Location = new Point(0, contactTiles.Count == 0 ? 0 : contactTiles.Last().Value.Bounds.Bottom) };
    contactTiles.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, ContactTile>(user.id, c));
    AddContactTile(c);
}
```

Stack trace:

```
StackTrace  "   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()   at     
System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateChildZOrder(Control ctl)   at 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)   at 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)   at 
System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m)   at 
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)"
```

Comment: In which thread a `ContactTile` is created before being added with `AddContactTile`?

Comment: I am creating it in the `AddContact` method which I will post as an edit. The `AddContact` method is the one that is actually called in the handler.

Comment: in begininvoke you need to pass an object array

Comment: "Invalid cross-thread operation message on the statusLabel control in the AddContactTile method." - but AddContactTile does not refer to statusLabel?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: So a `ContactTile` is created in a thread other than the UI thread, but in `AddContactTile` you are adding it in `mainPanel's` thread which I suppose is the UI thread. [_"It is unsafe to call a control from a thread other than the one that created the control"_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx). Try to create `ContactTile` instances also in the UI thread.

Comment: @manji please post your last comment as an answer; it fixed my issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContactTile` is created in a thread other than the UI thread, but in `AddContactTile` you are adding it in `mainPanel's` thread which I suppose is the UI thread. Following this rule [*"It is unsafe to call a control from a thread other than the one that created the control"*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx), try to create `ContactTile` instances also in the UI thread.

Comment: This solved my problem, I simply created and added the contact tile on a separate thread using new `Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate() { })).Start();` and the problem was fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Mutex and call `mutex.WaitOne();` prior to calling `.BeginInvoke(...);` or check the mutex from delegate itself.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx